# Is the following proof correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Is the following proof correct?

Let’s say we find integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2 ≡ y^2($mod $n)$ and $n$ has at least $2$ distinct factors not equal to $0$ or $n$.
I intend to show that there is at least $50$% chance that gcd$(n, x - y)$ is a non-trivial factor of $n$.

(Assume already proven that if we have an $x$ and $y$ which satisfy the rules $x$ is not congruent to $± y($mod $n)$ and $x^2 ≡ y^2($mod $n)$, then the greatest common divisor of $(x − y, n)$ and the greatest common divisor of $(x + y, n)$ will both be non-trivial factors of $n$.)
Then $(x – y)(x + y) = 0 ($mod $n)$ and the only possibilities for any gcd$(n, x + y)$ or gcd$(n, x - y)$ are that they equal either $n$, $1$, or a non-trivial factor of $n$.

If $x ≡ y($mod$ n)$, then gcd$(n, x - y) = n$.

If $x ≡ -y($mod $n)$, then gcd$(n, x - y) = 1$ or $n$

If x ≡ y(mod n), then gcd$(n, x + y) = 1$ or $n$

If $x ≡ -y($mod$ n)$, then gcd$(n, x + y) = n$

But if $x$ is not congruent to $± y($mod $n)$, then gcd($n, x + y$) does not equal 1 or n. So it must equal one of the at least 2 non-trivial factors of n.

So when $x^2 ≡ y^2($mod$ n)$, there is at least a 50% chance that gcd(n, x + y) is a non-trivial factor of n (a factor not equal to $1$, or $n$) .

Comment: anyone able to verify this or did I miss something?

Comment: I believe you mean $1$ or $n$ in the first line.

Comment: I do mean $0$ actually, just trying to imply that $n$ itself is not $0$ and letting it be true that if $n$ has $2$ distinct factors besides $0$ and $n$, then it has these factors in addition to $1$, so the fact that $2$ such distinct factors exist in addition to $n$ and $0$ implies that they do not equal $1$. But I see how that might not be exactly clear the way I tried to phrase it..

Comment: I would suggest "and $n \ne 0$ has ... to $n$" in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be $p^3$ a prime to the cube. Then if $x^2=y^2$ mod $n$ there is $0\%$ chance that $gcd(n,x-y)$ or $gcd(n,x+y)$ is neither $1$ nor $n$.

But $n$ has $p$ and $p^2$ which are two distinct factors of $n$.

The problem in your proof is that you always start with "if I have $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2=y^2$ and $x\neq \pm y$ then..." but it might happen that you can never find $x$ and $y$ verifying this (the condition is that $n$ has two distinct $\textit{prime}$ factors).

Actually if $n$ has exactly $r$ distinct prime factors and $gcd(a,n)=1$ then the equation $a=x^2$ mod $n$ has either $0$ solutions (if $a$ is not a square) and $2^r$ solutions if $a$ is a square. In that case having $x^2=y^2$ the probability that $x=\pm y$ is $\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}$.